# Update/Migrate Gradle project that only has build.gradle for project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a old app that was developed when Android Studio first came out. I've now came to update it but it's using the original version of gradle. It still uses the manifest to for version numbers and codes and doesn't have a build.gradle for the app, only the module (project).

How do I go about updating everything so it should have a build.gradle for the app as well as the module.

Comment: try importing the project in eclipse and then generate gradle files from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Updated Android Studio and Import your old project in it, Android studio will automatically create all missing build.gradle files for your project